# Joint distribution of residual in a simple linear regression model

Tags: regression, references, residuals

Please help me to understand the following concept:
Suppose we have the linear regression model $Y=XB+e$. The residual from this model can be written as: $r=(I-H)Y$ or $r=(I-H)e$ where $H$ is the hat matrix, equal to
 $X(X'X)^{-1}X'$.

Suppose now the distribution of the actual error vector $e$ is multivariate normal with mean vector $u$ and diagonal matrix $R$ then can we say that the joint distribution of residual vector will be multivariate normal?
What can we say about the joint distribution of residual vector $r$?

Please guide me with proper references.

Comment: Why would you need references?

Comment: Because i want to develop residual based test statistic for my problem

Comment: Why would that require references?

Comment: Because i am dealing with sample study

Comment: We seem not to be communicating at all. Why would references (rather than a direct answer to the question) be required for you to develop a test statistic in a sample study?